# $wpdb->wp_users returning empty value for

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, function

I have a code Example:

```
function custom_func(){
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->flush();     //tried with and without this line
    $getTest = 'SELECT * FROM $wpdb->wp_users LIMIT 1';
    $arrayReturned = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($getTest));
}
```

From what I've read I thought that $wpdb->wp_users is meant to have returned the database name and table name like so dbName.tableName; but it just returns an empty value.

I've tried:

```
$getTest = 'SELECT * FROM $wpdb->wp_users LIMIT 1';
```

which shows as the following to wordpress:

```
SELECT * FROM $wpdb->wp_users LIMIT 1
```

and

```
$getTest = 'SELECT * FROM '.$wpdb->wp_users.' LIMIT 1';
```

which shows as the following to wordpress:

```
SELECT * FROM  LIMIT 1
```

I can't fathom why this isn't working since this is all based on literature from the wordpress codex, any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to prefix the tables. As `$wpdb->table` will do it for you. Also you need to use double quotes `"` instead of single `'` because you are using `$wpdb` variable in your query string.

```
'SELECT * FROM $wpdb->wp_users LIMIT 1';
^---------------------^^^-------------^---
```

Use it without table prefix and with double quotes `"`.

```
"SELECT * FROM $wpdb->users LIMIT 1";
```

Also you don't need to use prepared statement because as there are no user input.

Your code should look like this:

```
function custom_func() {
    global $wpdb;
    $getTest = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->users LIMIT 1";
    $arrayReturned = $wpdb->get_results($getTest);
    var_dump($arrayReturned); // see results
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was exactly the problem I was having.